# Flutter Multiprovider with dependent streams

Tags: flutter

I'm want to make the User document from Firestore available to different widgets in my application. I'm listening to the authstate changes and getting the user ID, however, I'm not sure how to use that within a subsequent stream in my multiprovider :

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<FirebaseAuthService>(
          create: (_) => FirebaseAuthService(),
        ),
        //I'm looking to get another provider based on the provider above^^^ i.e the user id,
      ],
      child: getScreen(),
    );
```

---

```
class FirebaseAuthService {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user == null ? null : User(uid: user.uid);
  }

  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```